# How to make popup close?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I make my popup close?

```js
function togglePopup(){
  document.getElementById("popup-1").classList.toggle("active");
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Source+Sans+Pro&display=swap');

.popup .overlay{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  z-index: 1;
  display: none;
}

.popup .content{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform:translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0);
  background: #fff;
  width: 450px;
  height: 220px;
  z-index: 2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.popup .close-btn {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  top: 20px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background: #222;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.popup.active .overlay{
  display: block;
}

.popup.active .content{
  transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
transform:translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
}

h1{
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
}

p{
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
}

button{
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
<div class="popup" id="popup-1">
<div class="overlay"></div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="close-btn">&times;</div>
    <h1>Test Popup!</h1>
    <p>Test Popup! Test Popup! Test Popup! Test Popup! Test Popup! Test Popup! Test Popup! Test Popup! Test Popup! Test Popup! Test Popup! Test Popup! Test Popup! Test Popup! Test Popup! Test Popup! Test Popup! Test Popup! Test Popup!</p>
    </div>
    </div>

    <button onclick="togglePopup()">Open Popup</button>
```

Comment: If you want top quality, you don't roll your own and you use one that's already been made by someone else, is well tested, has lots of users, and clear documentation on how to use it. On a usability note, of course, a modal that pops up after 10 seconds can basically only be a nag-popup (like "sign up for my newsletter" or "become a member for more content") which kind of negates the whole top quality aspect: those just make your website worse, not better.

Comment: What specifically goes wrong? You don't seem to have coded anything for the "close" button.

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Stack Overflow is not a freelance site or a code-on-demand site. We will help you with code you are building, providing you are willing to put in the time and effort to tell us what is wrong with the code you are building.

Comment: @showdev the problem with the popup is that it can't close, and I gave up on the 10 second popup thing because Mike 'Pomax' Kamermans said that it could be annoying and just downgrade my website instead of upgrading.

Comment: @showdev thanks for editing the question. appreciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just attach a `click` event listener to the close button that calls the `togglePopup` function:

```js
function togglePopup() {
  document.getElementById("popup-1").classList.toggle("active");
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Source+Sans+Pro&display=swap');
.popup .overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  z-index: 1;
  display: none;
}

.popup .content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0);
  background: #fff;
  width: 450px;
  height: 220px;
  z-index: 2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.popup .close-btn {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  top: 20px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background: #222;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.popup.active .overlay {
  display: block;
}

.popup.active .content {
  transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
}

h1 {
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
}

p {
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
}

button {
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
<div class="popup" id="popup-1">
  <div class="overlay"></div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="close-btn" onclick="togglePopup()">&times;</div>
    <h1>Test Popup!</h1>
    <p>Test Popup! Test Popup! Test Popup! Test Popup! Test Popup! Test Popup! Test Popup! Test Popup! Test Popup! Test Popup! Test Popup! Test Popup! Test Popup! Test Popup! Test Popup! Test Popup! Test Popup! Test Popup! Test Popup!</p>
  </div>
</div>

<button onclick="togglePopup()">Open Popup</button>
```

To make the popup appear after 10 seconds, you can make use of `setTimeout`:

```js
function togglePopup() {
  document.getElementById("popup-1").classList.toggle("active");
}
setTimeout(togglePopup, 2000);  //to make it ten seconds, change the second parameter to 10000.
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Source+Sans+Pro&display=swap');
.popup .overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  z-index: 1;
  display: none;
}

.popup .content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0);
  background: #fff;
  width: 450px;
  height: 220px;
  z-index: 2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.popup .close-btn {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  top: 20px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background: #222;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.popup.active .overlay {
  display: block;
}

.popup.active .content {
  transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
}

h1 {
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
}

p {
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
}

button {
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
<div class="popup" id="popup-1">
  <div class="overlay"></div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="close-btn" onclick="togglePopup()">&times;</div>
    <h1>Test Popup!</h1>
    <p>Test Popup! Test Popup! Test Popup! Test Popup! Test Popup! Test Popup! Test Popup! Test Popup! Test Popup! Test Popup! Test Popup! Test Popup! Test Popup! Test Popup! Test Popup! Test Popup! Test Popup! Test Popup! Test Popup!</p>
  </div>
</div>

<button onclick="togglePopup()">Open Popup</button>
```